# How to save and load objects in Java? I have tried, but it keeps throwing the IOexception

Tags: java, serialization

```
public class DriverClass implements Serializable {
    CafeManager cafe = new CafeManager(); - Creates the object 

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        CafeManager newcafe;

        newcafe = load(); - Calls the load module

        SystemMenu menu = new SystemMenu();
        menu.displaymenu(); - Running of the menu


        newcafe = new CafeManager(newcafe.getMenuItems(),newcafe.getOrders()); - Once the user exits the menu, file should be saved


        save(newcafe);

    }

    public static void save(CafeManager newcafe) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        try{
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("system.dat");

            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

            out.writeObject(newcafe);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fe){
            System.out.println("File Not found.");
        }
        catch (IOException ie){
            System.out.println("File Crappy" + ie.getMessage()); //Output: File Crappycafesys.Order
        }

    }

    public static CafeManager load() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        CafeManager curcafe = new CafeManager();
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("system.dat");

        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);

        try{
            curcafe = (CafeManager) in.readObject();
        }
        catch(ClassCastException | ClassNotFoundException ce){
            //
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fe){
            System.out.println("File Not found.");
        }
        catch (IOException ie){
            System.out.println("File Crappy" + ie.getMessage()); //Output: File Crappy writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: cafesys.Order
        }

        return curcafe;
    }
```

I'm not sure why `IOException` is caught. As I have created the file and run it through the `ObjectOutputStream`. The exception message is:

> `java.io.NotSerializableException: cafesys.Order`

Comment: Maybe because the file is crappy?

Comment: It says: `File Crappy writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: cafesys.Order`. It means: first, that your file is crappy, second, that `cafesys.Order` is not serializable. Find `cafesys.Order` and make it serialiazable.

Comment: Haha @CocoNess really funny...